# JDBI: How to cast Java Long to postgresql "bigint" in sql statement?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, casting, jdbi

I'm having quite a bit of trouble preparing this SQL statement for PostgreSQL using JDBI. I get an error when trying to apply a Java Long to a SQL column type of bigint. When I execute the following:

```
Long valLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
handle.createQuery("INSERT INTO table (valCol)"
                    + "VALUES (:val) "
                + "RETURNING *")
                    .bind("val", valLong)
                    .map(Mapper.instance)
                    .list());
```

I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "val" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying
```

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Please include the full Java code along with the Postgres table definition.

Comment: How exactly is `valLong` defined in Java?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is set as Long valLong = System.currentTimeMillis();